# Clean way to find exactly 3 instances of x in a list and exactly 2 instances of y?

Tags: python

No this isn't just as simple as using `count()`

I've got a list of 5 random integers from 0-9. I want to check if 3 of these integers are identical, and if the remaining 2 are identical but different from the other 3.

My idea was to use `set()` to count the occurrences that exist in the list, but this also includes cases where there are 4 identical integers and 1 lone integer, like so:

```
nums = [4, 4, 4, 2, 2]
if len(set(nums)) == 2:
    print(set(nums))

>> {4, 2}


nums = [4, 4, 4, 4, 2]
if len(set(nums)) == 2:
    print(set(nums))

>> {4, 2}
```

I've been trying to find a way to exclude the 4x1 cases, but everything I've come up with seems convoluted and like bad practice, and this needs to be clean. I'm wondering if maybe there is a better way to do this without using set()?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: is my answer what you're looking for?

Comment: Should `[1, 2, 1, 2, 1]` match? If yes, then you would want to change "different from the first 3" to just "different from the 3". If no, then you would want to change "check if 3 of these integers" to "check if the first 3 integers".

Comment: @Abhishek yes, thank you that worked nicely

Comment: @ShioT Yes it would, thanks I've edited my description

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a dictionary having the number as key and value as its frequency

```
from collections import Counter
nums = [4, 4, 4, 2, 2]

freq_dict = dict(Counter(nums))
print(freq_dict)
```

would give you this:

```
{4: 3, 2: 2}
```

and then we can check for the condition that the length of the dictionary is 2, otherwise it means it has more than 2 identical elements.

```
if len(freq_dict) == 2:

    for key, value in freq_dict.items():
        if value == 2 or value == 3:
            print("Given that there are 5 items and the length of the list is 2, it has to be the case that \ 
                  the other integer appears {} times".format(5 - value))
            print(key)
            break

        else:
            print("Nope")
```